# Xcode13 Undefined symbol: ___gcov_flush

Tags: code-coverage, flush, gcov, xcode13

For code coverage, I upgraded to xcode13 and used extern to export the built-in function 'Gcov'. Xcode13 reported an error of "undefined symbol: __gcov_flush". I'm good on xcode12. Does anyone encounter this problem?

The specific error reports are as follows：

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "___gcov_flush", referenced from: -[AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new llvm use __gcov_dump().  Place use new LLVM